# Implementing Kalman Filter for Improved Measurement Accuracy in Autonomous Two-Wheeled Robot with Encoders

Tags: pid, robotics, kalman-filter, encoder

So i am a beginner in the field of robotics, and I have successfully created an autonomous two-wheeled robot equipped with two encoders. I've implemented a PI regulation on speed, and while the robot performs reasonably well, I still encounter some measurement errors. To enhance its performance, I'm considering the implementation of a Kalman filter.

While I have a theoretical understanding of the Kalman filter, I'm a bit confused about the practical implementation. Should I apply a simple Kalman filter to each encoder independently to smooth the measurements, or is it more appropriate to use the filter on the x and y positions of the robot? . Any guidance on the best approach for implementing the Kalman filter in this context would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: At the end of the day, is the (x, y) position of the robot what you care about? If so, then it probably makes sense to have those be the states of the filter. Are there any other measurements that you get about the position of the vehicle? If the encoders is all that you have, a Kalman Filter probably won't help you all that much. The dynamics in the filter would be driven by the encoder, but there are no measurements to correct the state estimate, so uncertainty would just keep growing over time.